# reading/writing preferences

Tags: firefox-addon

I have read most all of the documentation and questions related to preferences I could find but I have an error that is always coming up no matter what method I try and I do not understand it.

js file loaded in browser overlay xul

```
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].
                getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService).
                getBranch("extensions.{my-guid-id}.");

var value = prefs.getBoolPref("firstrun");
```

defaults/preferences/prefs.js:

```
pref("extensions.{my-guid-id}.firstrun", true);
```

The error message in the error console says `uncaught exception: "compenent returned failure code 0x8000ffff" on  line 27` which is right at `getBoolPref()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct.

Are you sure that you did not put the word true in quotes or accidentally already set it as a non boolean preferences?

I would suggest going into about:config and verifying that your firstrun preference is showing up as a Boolean.

That's the most common cause of the problem you are seeing.

Comment: You're right, the preference is not shown in about:config. My defaults/preferences dir was in my chrome folder which is my main content folder.  How can I update the manifest file to point to the preferences dir? Thanks for your help, infact Mike I just replied to your blog post on this so you can ignore that.

Comment: I thought that was you commenting on my blog post.

The defaults/preferences dir goes at the very top level of your add-on. You can't point to it via the manifest. As long as you put it there, it will be good.